extract data from nested json using pyspark dataframe
I have the following data in a column called json_col for a dataframe product in databricks which has additional columns as well.
The data for json_col has data as below
html:null ,language:null ,message:null ,product:{"title":"selecteddata","search_alias":{"title":"Home ","value":"kitchen"},,"content":{"all_images":[{"ee":"eeee","name":"front page asdsadaasdasd"},{"dasdas":"sduahdjka","name":"asdsadaasdasd"},{"dasdas":"edkjas","name":"asdsadaasdasd "},{"dasdas":"dakjs","name":"Plumeri asdsadaasdasd Spucktüche"},"dasdas":"dkasjhasdasnd","name":"diasdjaskldnasn"}],"body_text":"dkjasda,"},"climate_pledge_friendly":"No",}

out of the all i need to select only the content data that is only
{"all_images":[{"ee":"eeee","name":"front page asdsadaasdasd"},{"dasdas":"sduahdjka","name":"asdsadaasdasd"},{"dasdas":"edkjas","name":"asdsadaasdasd "},{"dasdas":"dakjs","name":"Plumeri asdsadaasdasd Spucktüche"},"dasdas":"dkasjhasdasnd","name":"diasdjaskldnasn"}],"body_text":"dkjasda,"}

I am using the following
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, get_json_object

# Extract a_plus_content as a dictionary
extracted_data = product.withColumn('content_extract', get_json_object('json_col', '$.content'))

# Show the results (optional)
extracted_data.select('content_extract').show()

however its appearing as null.
can we have some expert advice or other solution to fix the issue above

Extracts json object from a json string based on json path specified, and returns json string of the extracted json object. It will return null if the input json string is invalid.
https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.get_json_object.html

please add complete json and expected output

is shared in the question as The data for column json_col from the dataframe product  has data as below and out of the all i need to select only the content data that is only where content is the attiribute.

thats not valid json.. please add valid json and expected output

Use from_json function with schema to extract specific part from json string. Check below code.
product
.withColumn(
  "content", 
  expr("from_json(json_col, 'product struct<content:string>').product.content")
)
.select("content")
.show(2, False)

+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|content                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"all_images":[{"ee":"eeee","name":"front page asdsadaasdasd"},{"dasdas":"sduahdjka","name":"asdsadaasdasd"},{"dasdas":"edkjas","name":"asdsadaasdasd "},{"dasdas":"dakjs","name":"Plumeri asdsadaasdasd Spucktüche"},{"dasdas":"dkasjhasdasnd","name":"diasdjaskldnasn"}],"body_text":"dkjasda,"}|
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

